# Firebase Remote Config randomly returning wrong value

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-remote-config

We have a remote config flag named (For .e.g `ABC_Flag`) with `Boolean` type

Production Key:
ABC_Flag_key = false

Development Key:
ABC_Flag_key_debug = false

Both Production and Development keys are configured in separate projects on Firebase portal.

However, the value for the production key (for around 3-4% users) is being returned as `true` (instead of `false`) by Firebase swift SDK and hence severely affecting users' access, and they are not able to use our app at all. We are not able to figure out in what scenario this might be possible, but we have seen this happen to one of our test devices. This is to note that we haven't changed the value of the production flag for a long time.

Any help would be greatly appreciated to understand why this SDK is fetching wrong values

Comment: Any news about this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem,
some users have wrong flag values from remote config.
with version of Firebase/RemoteConfig is `7.8.1`
I found this issue
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/4206
it seem be solved,
this issue is closed but i still have the problem with version `7.8.1`

Comment: We are experiencing this too. Did you find a solution?